# SELECT TOP 1 from a very large table on an index column is very slow, but not with reverse order ("desc")

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, performance, select, top, query-performance

We have a large database, about 1TB, running SQL Server 2014 on a powerful server. Everything worked fine for a few years.  About 2 weeks ago, we did a full maintenance, which included: Install all software updates; rebuild all indexes and compact DB files. However, we did not expect that at certain stage the DB's CPU usage increased by over 100% to 150% when the actual load was the same.

After a lot of troubleshooting, we have narrowed it down to a very simple query, but we could not find a solution. The query is extremely simple:

```
select top 1 EventID from EventLog with (nolock) order by EventID
```

It always takes about 1.5 seconds! However, a similar query with "desc" always takes about 0 ms:

```
select top 1 EventID from EventLog with (nolock) order by EventID desc
```

PTable has about 500 million rows; `EventID` is the primary clustered index column (ordered `ASC`) with the data type of bigint (Identity column). There are multiple threads inserting data into the table at the top (larger EventIDs), and there is 1 thread deleting data from the bottom (smaller EventIDs).

In SMSS, we verified that the two queries always use the same execution plan:

- Clustered index scan;
- Estimated and actual row numbers are both 1;
- Estimated and actual number of executions are both 1;
- Estimate I/O cost is 8500 (Seems to be high)
- If run consecutively, the Query cost is the same 50% for both.

I updated index statistics `with fullscan`, the problem persisted; I rebuilt the index again, and the problem seemed to be gone for half a day, but came back.

I turned on IO statistics with:

```
set statistics io on
```

then ran the two queries consecutively and found the following info:

(For the first query, the slow one)

> Table 'PTable'. Scan count 1, logical reads 407670, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

(For the second query, the fast one)

> Table 'PTable'. Scan count 1, logical reads 4, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

Note the huge difference in logical reads. The index is used in both cases.

Index fragmentation could explain a little bit, but I believe the impact is very small; and the problem never happened before. Another proof is if I run a query like:

```
select * from EventLog with (nolock) where EventID=xxxx
```

Even if I set xxxx to the smallest EventIDs in the table, the query is always lightning fast.

We checked and there is no locking/blocking issue.

Note: I just tried to simplify the issue above. The "PTable" is actually "EventLog"; the `PID` is `EventID`.

I get the same result testing without the `NOLOCK` hint.

Can anybody help?

[image]

[image]

More detailed query execution plans in XML as follows:

https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=SJ3eiVnob

https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=r1rOjVhoZ

I don't think it matters to provide the create table statement. It is an old database and has been running perfectly fine for a long time until the maintenance.  We have done a lot of research ourselves and narrowed it down to the info provided in my question.

The table was created normally with the `EventID` column as the primary key, which is an `identity` column of type `bigint`. At this time, I guess the problem is with the index fragmentation. Right after index rebuild, the problem seemed to be gone for half a day; but why it came back so quickly...?

Answer (score 18):

The Clustered Index Scan shows 423,723 logical reads to return the first row, taking 1926 ms:

[image: NUTS]

This seems rather a lot to locate the first row in index order.

Most likely your **ghost cleanup** task is running a long way behind, or has stopped. You should check the `ghost_record_count` for the clustered index in [`sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-db-index-physical-stats-transact-sql) and monitor changes over time.

The **ordered scan** from the end of the index that is seeing constant delete activity has to scan over an awful lot of ghosted records before it finds the first 'alive' row to return. This explains the extra logical reads. A seek down the b-tree to the lowest value of the index will encounter much fewer ghosted records.

Another performance-affecting factor is that the scan itself becomes responsible for removing the ghost records as mentioned in [Inside the Storage Engine: Ghost cleanup in depth](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/inside-the-storage-engine-ghost-cleanup-in-depth/) by Paul Randal.

You should check that trace flag 661 (disable ghost cleanup) is not active.

#### Solutions

- You may find that running [sp_clean_db_free_space](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-db-index-physical-stats-transact-sql) provides relief.
- Changing the process that deletes rows from that end of the index to use a `PAGLOCK` hint [would enable ghost cleanup on the spot](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqljourney/2012/07/27/an-in-depth-look-at-ghost-records-in-sql-server), which could well solve the problem as well.

If the ghost cleanup process has stopped completely, the most effective solution is normally to restart the SQL Server instance. You should also ensure that the SQL Server is running one of the latest Cumulative Updates. There have been many ghost cleanup bugs over the years.

In your specific case:

> It turned out the problem was caused by another test database on the same server. That test database was restored with "data loss", and is corrupt. Surprisingly, the ghost cleanup process apparently was stuck in that database. Once we deleted that corrupted database from SMSS, the problem resolved by itself (took a long time and might have caused DB to lockup for a short while).